# F# - Creating program to read a file and print in reverse, how do I remove all the new line quotations?

Tags: list, f#

I have a program where if I type "tac Text.txt" (or any file path in quotations, but this is the test text file I made/used), it will print what is in the `txt` file, but in reverse. But it doesn't work properly. Where it should appear as

```
No it is not.


Yes-it is.
No it is not.
Hello  my  name  is  Jim.
```

it appears as

```
["No it is not."; ""; ""; "Yes-it is."; "No it is not.";  "Hello  my 
name  is  Jim."].
```

My code currently is

```
open System
open System.IO

let countLines path = 
    File.ReadAllLines(path) |> Seq.toList|> List.rev



    // File.ReadAllLines reads the file, turns it into a list then reverses the list.


let printFunction lines = 
    printfn "%A" lines

    // This, when called, will print the file in reverse. 

let tac path =
    if File.Exists(path) then
        let lines = countLines path
        printFunction lines
    else
        printfn "File not found."

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    if argv.Length > 0 then
        tac argv.[0] 
    else
        printfn "Error - Please enter file path."
    0
```

I'm assuming it's due to converting to a list, is there a way I can print it normally? I'm hoping it's just a small rookie mistake I've made.

UPDATE: I just changed

```
let countLines path = 
File.ReadAllLines(path) |> Seq.toList|> List.rev
```

to

```
let countLines path = 
File.ReadAllLines(path) |> Array.rev
```

Same thing happens, but I'm hoping it leads me closer to the result I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's writing out your entire data type, which is a `string list`.

You need to iterate through the list:

```
let printFunction lines = 
    for line in lines do printfn "%s" line
```

Comment: It is also worth looking at Asti's answer, and working out why it works. It's a good example of how partial function application works in F#.

Answer (score 2):

Print an array, list or seq of lines individually:

```
let printFunction = Seq.iter (printfn "%s")
```